# backbone.js setting view el id attribute using model dynamically

Tags: backbone.js

I am working with backbone.js v 0.5.3.

I am wondering if there is a better way to set the id property of a view element. It seems redundant to always have to set it like so:

```
view = new Views.Foo( model: @model, id: 'foo-' + @model.id )
```

It would be nice if I could define the id in the view class like so

```
class Views.Foo extends Backbone.View
  id: 'foo-' + @model.id
```

It is kind of nitpicky but I find myself defining id and data-attributes way too often.

Has anyone come up with a good way to initialize view el attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it to the constructor:

```
class Views.Foo extends Backbone.View
    initialize: (options)->
        @id = 'foo-' + @model.id
        $(@el).attr 'id', @id
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, but it seems like I am missing something that backbone might already do.